# ClearCase UCM Mainline Configuration Management Pattern Question

Tags: clearcase, configuration-management, clearcase-ucm

A configuration management pattern question (using Rational ClearCase UCM)

When I use the mainline approach I create new releases by:

- create release 1 from mainline
- on a certain moment baseline release 1, deliver release 1 to mainline
- create release 2 from mainline
- on a certain moment baseline release 2, deliver release 2 to mainline
- create release 3 from mainline
- etc...

Works very nice because the pathname is `/main/release 3/latest` instead of `/main/release 1/release 2/release 3/latest` etc...

However... when in release 1 are new elements that have to be propagated to later releases I can not use the mainline since the mainline is already on e.g. release 4.

The only thing I can do is deliver/merge from release 1 directly to release 2.
The bad thing is that the pathname then becomes `/main/release 1/release 2/latest` for that files (and possibly later releases). That is I think not in line with the mainline approach.

What am I doing wrong?

crossposted on: http://www.cmcrossroads.com/forums?func=view&catid=31&id=99369#99369
crossposted on: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=330226

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the **cascading branching** symptom.

In your case, though, whenever there are "new elements that have to be propagated to later releases", you should be able to deliver them directly from release1 to release2 with a cascade limited to two-levels depth.

If that is not acceptable, you need to setup your streams in order to have a "global stream" *above* mainline and above the releases:

```
mainStream
  mainline
  release1
  release2
  ...
```

You can use mainStream as the source from which you propagate changes:
clearfsimport release2 on mainStream, import/deliver the few release1 files to be propagated, make (again) a "release2" baseline, and rebase it on the release2 stream.

- on the minus side, you need to repeat the process for each release.
- on the plus side, at least, each clearfsimport (on mainStream) is "quick enough" because the delta between release is not too important.